# ecryptfs - Encrypting identical files with the same key leads to different results

Tags: linux, filesystems, encryption, ecryptfs

My understanding so far has been that ecryptfs uses a wrapped passphrase to encrypt files.
When I mount two pairs of encrypted/decrypted directories using the same key I expect the same result when encrypting the key. However, this seems not to be true:

```
$ sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_sig=f8ac65b530d4aebc,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_xattr=y safe1/ open1
$ sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_sig=f8ac65b530d4aebc,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_xattr=y safe2/ open2
$ echo "Hi" > open1/testfile
$ cp -a open1/testfile open2/testfile 
$ md5sum open*/testfile
31ebdfce8b77ac49d7f5506dd1495830  open1/testfile
31ebdfce8b77ac49d7f5506dd1495830  open2/testfile
$ md5sum safe*/testfile
4fe5016ca0b9b283fd05e03ccaee0b14  safe1/testfile
75850506e568f60a77acd96dfb2d2895  safe2/testfile
```

I think this is not related to the content of the file but to some metadata. Because when I copy encrypted file from one space to the other I can decrypt the content

```
$ umount open*
$ cp -a safe2/testfile safe1/testfile2
$ sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_sig=f8ac65b530d4aebc,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_xattr=y safe1/ open1
$ sudo mount -i -t ecryptfs -o ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,ecryptfs_sig=f8ac65b530d4aebc,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_xattr=y safe2/ open2
$ cat open1/testfile2 
Hi
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

What I'm looking for is a way that the encrypted file in the example above are identical.

Comment: `stat open1/testfile
  File: open1/testfile
  Size: 3               Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 34h/52d Inode: 55072471    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2018-04-25 22:12:17.751442350 +0200
Modify: 2018-04-25 22:12:02.671242560 +0200
Change: 2018-04-25 22:12:02.671242560 +0200
 Birth: -`

Comment: `stat open2/testfile
  File: open2/testfile
  Size: 3               Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 35h/53d Inode: 55072472    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2018-04-25 22:12:29.655599945 +0200
Modify: 2018-04-25 22:12:02.671242560 +0200
Change: 2018-04-25 22:12:17.751442350 +0200
 Birth: -`

Comment: Creating the file twice (in open1 and open2) instead of `cp` is causing different md5sums as well

Comment: ^^^ Can you please put the information in those comments into your question, where they belong. For starters, it's easier to format legibly, and to go on with it makes it easy for people to read and understand your question if they don't have to dig through a comment trail. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in encrypted value is by design. Each encrypted file has a [per-file randomly generated session key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs).